# How to create Photoshop Layers with Names in Wand 0.6.5

Tags: python, wand

I am looking for an example to create an image with python ImageMagic Wand with named layers. How do you set the Layer names for a photoshop (PSD) file?

````
```# Create Image (Layer0)
with Image( 
    width=int(configuration['layer0']['width']), 
    height=int(configuration['layer0']['height']), 
    background=Color('Lime'),
    format='psd'
          ) as boxcover:
    
    boxcover.iterator_first()
    boxcover.pseudo(4096,2048, 'xc:gold')
    
    with Drawing() as layer:
        layer.font_size = 72
        layer.font_family = 'Arial'
        layer.text(100,100,'Hello')
        layer.draw(boxcover)
      
    boxcover.iterator_set(1)
    boxcover.pseudo(4096,2048, 'xc:purple')
        

    
    debug_layers(boxcover,'/Users/colin/Downloads/debug.png')
    boxcover.save(filename='/Users/colin/Downloads/test1.psd')
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have much experience with PSD format, but with [wand](/questions/tagged/wand), you would need to set the `'label'` property (`Image.options['label']`) before reading / creating a new layer.

```py
with Image(width=4096, height=2048, pseudo='xc:lime') as boxcover:
    boxcover.options['label'] = 'First Layer'
    boxcover.pseudo(4096,2048, 'xc:gold')
    with Drawing() as layer:
        layer.font_size = 72
        layer.font_family = 'Arial'
        layer.text(100,100,'Hello')
        layer.draw(boxcover)
    boxcover.options['label'] = 'Second Layer'
    boxcover.pseudo(4096,2048, 'xc:purple')
    boxcover.save(filename='test1.psd')
```

And we can verify with `identify` utility.

```
$ identify -format '%[filename] %[page] %[label]\n' test1.psd
test1.psd 4096x2048 
test1.psd 4096x2048 First Layer
test1.psd 4096x2048 Second Layer
```